# VS 2019 unable to show designer for UWP while using Windows 10 version 1803 (can SDK work?)

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2019, xamarin.uwp

Our company has standardized all PC's on Windows 10, version 1803. We discovered that UWP will not display the XAML designer in Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.2.5). The error is as follows:

"Visual Studio requires a newer version of Windows to display this content.
Please update to Windows 10, version 1903 (10.0.18362.0) or later."

I have tried in vain to see if there's a solution to this problem without having to upgrade Windows 10 which is a non-starter. At one time, I found a suggestion to download the Windows 10 version 1903 SDK and I just tried that with no success. However, I might not have installed the exact MSI that's required as there's a laundry list of MSI's that come in that SDK. Or, there's something else I'm neglecting to do. Or, we're simply out of luck and will have to work without the designer as our company will likely not authorize a Win10 upgrade for at least another year.

**UPDATED with SDK showing in folder**

[image: SDK installed]

Comment: I get that error as well, having clicked "snooze" on the Win10 update prompt for a while.  Project > Properties > Application tab, Target version.  Don't go higher than "Windows 10 Fall Creators Update".  Why picking 1809 doesn't work is mysterious.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only choice for Target is 1903 on my machine. I tried setting the source as Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (just for kicks) with the same result.

Comment: You do need to have the SDK for it installed.  Look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include, you need to have 10.0.16299.0 there.

Comment: Hans, I feel I'm close, because I do already have the SDK installed (a later version that happens to match what the designer message is displaying) as seen in my edited post above. I rebooted the PC with no luck.

Comment: This is where you let your IT support staff call Microsoft Support.  Since they created the problem it is their job to fix it.  With a nice potential side-effect that they'll retire that silly update policy.

Comment: Hans, unfortunately with as with just about any corporate enterprise, that won't work. I've already inquired into it and it's a very involved procedure in order to prove out how any OS upgrade will affect everyone across the company. And, it's simply not possible, due to how software is managed, to update a single box with an OS upgrade. Software stability and security are of paramount concern for the company.

Comment: Hmm, never heard of an enterprise that didn't have IT support staff.  It is your cross to bear, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case installing SDK 16299 helped (after retargeting solution to this SDK and building project).